# Pronunciation of 'fragile'

Tags: pronunciation

In my dictionary, fragile can be pronounced as frædʒaɪl or  ˋfrædʒəl. I am wondering which one is correct. Or it's regional? How is it pronounced by native speakers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's at least partly regional.

I speak British English, and prnounce "fragile" and "missile" with /aɪl/, as is the norm in BrE. The /əl/ pronunciation is American, as far as I know.

Comment: Unless, of course, it's of the *supercali* sort. :P

Comment: @Lawrence, in nonce words like "fragilism", "fragilistic", or "fragilation", most BrE speakers would naturally pronounce it with  /dʒɪl/ (not /dʒəl/) because of [trisyllabic laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing). They may be uncertain whether or not to double the 'l' in writing the last one, though!

Comment: Well played. :)

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries, at least for English, are **de**scriptive, not **pre**scriptive - that is, they tell you generally what *is*, rather than what *should be* (although there is often a lag between a change in usage or pronunciation and its incorporation into the next edition/update). Where multiple meanings, usages, or pronunciations are given, they should all be assumed to be 'correct', subject to annotations showing limitations (e.g., *vulg* for vulgar usage, or *chiefly British*, etc.).

For your specific question (*fragile*), I generally hear it in the NYC area as `/ˋfrædʒəl/`, but have heard other pronunciations in other parts of the US.